# syntax error when using ifstream

Tags: c++

It's been a long time since I've done any C++.  What's wrong with this code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
main()
{
    ifstream& ifs("foo.txt");
}
```

Gives:

```
$ g++ foo.cc 
foo.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
foo.cc:7:25: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘std::ifstream& {aka std::basic_ifstream<char>&}’ from an rvalue of type ‘const char*’
  ifstream& ifs("foo.txt");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing values by reference isn't done in the variable declaration, but instead in the parameter list of the function using the ifstream object. For example, your function main might look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ifstream ifs("foo.txt");
    myFunction(ifs);
}
```

and your called function should look like this:

```
void myFunction(std::ifstream& in_stream)
{
    // ...
}
```

If you need the C++11 reference type (which I doubt, but maybe), try this:

```
ifstream ifs("foo.txt.");
std::ref<std::ifstream> ifs_ref(ifs);
```

That works in a lot of cases where doing a regular by-ref wouldn't.

Answer (score 3):

You used a `&` when you should not have done.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ifstream ifs("foo.txt");
}
```

Comment: I need a reference to an ifstream, so I do need an &.  

See http://udt.sourceforge.net/udt4/index.htm for why.

Comment: @NigelHorne: That makes no sense, and nothing on that webpage tells me otherwise. References refer to objects that already exist; here you're declaring one for the first time.

Comment: Here's the line in the code on the webpage "ifstream& ifs("largefile.dat");"  So I am trying to do exactly that, but I get a syntax error when I do.  I believe that is a declaration, not an object that already exists.

Comment: @NigelHorne: The webpage is wrong. I don't know what else to tell you. The syntax error is your one major clue to that.

Comment: I tried without a reference before posting here, but then the call to UDT::sendfile fails to compile.  I assumed, and I may be wrong, that it is because it needs a reference.

Comment: @NigelHorne: What call to `UDT::sendfile`? You haven't shown us that. But, anyway, `ifs` is always going to be an actual object, not a reference. You can declare a reference to `ifs` if you like (I doubt you actually need to), but you have to properly declare it as an actual object first. Now that your declaration is correct (thanks, me!) it's time to figure out why the call to `UDT::sendfile` is failing.

Answer (score 0):

semantically, a reference is a pointer. so your code doesn't compile for the same reason this code doesn't:

```
main()
{
  ifstream* ifs("foo.txt");
}
```

as others have said, you want to create an object of type ifstream. not a reference (nor a pointer) to it.